# How to properly test a compareTo() method with custom exceptions in Java?

Tags: java, exception, junit

Having problems testing a `compareTo()` method with custom exception. How do I throw a custom exception without compilation error?

Code of the Junit test

```
 @Test
    public void compareTo() {
        // check equals
        assertEquals(0, competitionDressageQualifier.compareTo(competitionDressageQualifier));
        try {
            Competition c1 = new Competition(competitionDressageQualifier.getEvent(), competitionDressageQualifier.getCompetitionDate(),
                    competitionDressageQualifier.getJudges(), competitionDressageQualifier.getCompetitionLevel());
            assertEquals(0, c1.compareTo(competitionDressageQualifier));
            assertEquals(0, competitionDressageQualifier.compareTo(c1));
        } catch (OlympicException ex) { //I HAVE THE ERROR HERE Unreachable catch block for OlympicException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body
            // this shouldn't happen
            fail();
        }
```

Code of the `compareTo()`; how do I implement try catch here exactly?

```
@Override
    public int compareTo(Competition o) //compare properties
    {
        
        if(!Objects.equals(this.getCompetitionDate(), o.getCompetitionDate())) //first date
        {
            return (this.getCompetitionDate().compareTo(o.getCompetitionDate()));
        }
        
        else
        {
            if(!Objects.equals(this.competitionlevel, o.competitionlevel)) //seconds comp level
            {
                return (this.competitionlevel.compareTo(o.competitionlevel));
            }
            else
            {
            
                    if(!Objects.equals(this.getEvent().getEventName(), o.getEvent().getEventName())) //third priority is event name
                    {
                        return (this.getEvent().getEventName().compareTo(o.getEvent().getEventName()));
                    }
                
            }
        }       
        return 0; //if same return 0
    }
```

Code of the custom exception:

```
public class OlympicException extends Exception {

    private long serialVersionUID=-1;
   
    public OlympicException()
       {
          // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
       }

       public OlympicException( String s )
       {
          super( s );
          // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
       }

       public OlympicException( Throwable cause )
       {
          super( cause );
          // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
       }

       public OlympicException( String s, Throwable cause )
       {
          super( s, cause );
          // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
       }

}
```

No matter what I try I get a compilation error. Am I comparing some stuff in the wrong way?

Comment: The compilater say that you want to catch an `OlympicException` but nothing in your `try` can throw one. Why do you use a try/catch here ?

Comment: Why do you leave all the `// TODO`s in your code? That's ugly and messy. Why are you trying to catch an exception that is never thrown? Where do you expect this exception to be thrown in your code?

Comment: The only exception I can see that would be thrown by your code is NullPointerException if any of the values are null. Note: There's no need for an `else` after an `if` with a `return`.

Answer (score -1):

Make it a `RuntimeException`:

```
public class OlympicException extends RuntimeException {
```

That will fix your compilation error, and allow your `compareTo()` impl to throw it.

Comment: `compareTo` methods shouldn't throw any exceptions apart from `NullPointerException` if the passed argument is `null`, or `ClassCastException` if the argument isn't compatible. The latter is mostly a left-over from the pre-generic days.

Comment: @RobSpoor "shouldn't"? Any method can throw any runtime exception without violating any contract of principle. Your examples are common runtime exceptions thrown by compareTo, but there is no express or implied requirement to restrict runtime exceptions thrown to be only those two.

Comment: I didn't say "cannot" because you're right - any runtime exception can be thrown from any method. However, they "shouldn't" because of the specification: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T). If an implementation throws other exceptions that will be unexpected and can lead to very odd bugs in code. For instance, `TreeMap` instances can start throwing exceptions that nobody expects, and therefore nobody will try to catch.